# is it possible to change the actions of the UIButtons for the UIImagePickerController.. i.e.(cancel, use, retake..etc...)?

Tags: ios

is it possible to change the default actions of the UIButtons for the UIImagePickerController. i.e.(cancel, use, retake, etc.)?

For example, after I take a picture and tap 'use', I am taken to the photo albums view controller. Can I set it up to instead just reload the UIImagePickerController?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *newOverlay = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIButton *newButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
newButton.frame = CGRectMake(20,40,70,40);
[myButton addTarget:self 
         action:@selector(yourAction:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[newOverlay addSubview:newButton];

picker.cameraOverlayView = newOverlay;
```

Just keep adding buttons to your newOverlay and set the actions!

Comment: I'm trying to do this very thing too, even if I am programming in Swift. Ehm, should I want to change the buttons actions, I guess I should create 2 overlays right? one with "cancel" and "shoot" button, and one with "retake" and "use photo" buttons...is this right?